# Bluetooth HSP support on Windows XP without third-party drivers

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, bluetooth, headset

Can the Windows XP built-in Bluetooth stack support HSP (headset profile) as an extra audio device, without third-party drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP supports - PAN, SPP, DUN, HID, HCRP out of the box... Looking in the [support documentation](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/Bth_FAQ.docx), but can't find support for headsets.

You could always use an alternative Bluetooth stack at your own risk.

(From Windows 7 guide above)

```
Windows includes in-box support for the Bluetooth profiles that are listed in Table 3.
Table 3. In-Box Bluetooth Profiles
Profile Description
HID v1.0    Human Input Device
PANU    Personal Area Network User
SPP Serial Port Profile 
OPP Object Push Profile
DUN Dial-Up Networking
HCRP    Hard Copy Replacement Profile
```

So, if Windows 7 doesn't support it, I am pretty sure XP won't

Comment: Windows 7 supports it, but it seems like Windows XP does not. I just have to find the driver CD that came with my 99c dongle...